# Byte conversion from 32 bit to 8 bit

Tags: c#

hi this *I* want to send this hex vales but i am getting error..  I am send byte values ,** my error.. constant vales cannot be converted to byte.**

```
class constant(){
public const byte MESSAGE_START = 0x1020; // command hex
}


public override IEnumerable<byte> ToBytes()
        {
      yield return constant.MESSAGE_START ;

    }
```

HI, there is another twist i am facing, though with your help I passed the hex value, I should decimal equivalent when i pass through the below method, but value I get is 16.

protected override void TransmitCommand(Device device, Command command)
        {
            int count = 0;

```
        foreach (var b in command.ToBytes())
            transmitBuffer[count++] = b;   // values i get is 16 but not decimal values 4128
    }
```

Comment: This is not valid C#.    `yield return` can only be used in a method that returns IEnumerable<T>.  `MESSAGE_START` is a `short` not a `byte`.

Comment: HI, Sorry, plse check now.

Comment: byte[] results = BitConverter.GetBytes(1234567890);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the value `MESSAGE_START` is a `short` not a `byte`.  Try this

```
class constant() {
  public const short MESSAGE_START = 0x1020; // command hex
}

public override IEnumerable<byte> ToBytes()
{
  yield return (byte) (constant.MESSAGE_START >> 8);
  yield return (byte) (constant.MESSAGE_START & 0xff);
}
```

The above code assumes that the byte representation of the value is in [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (most significant byte first). For **LSB** do

```
public override IEnumerable<byte> ToBytes()
{
  yield return (byte) (constant.MESSAGE_START & 0xFF);
  yield return (byte) (constant.MESSAGE_START >> 8);
}
```

Comment: OK and should i later cast it to byte since I am passing them a byte?

Comment: What? `ToBytes` is casting.

Comment: HI please check my code as i am facing a new issue.

Comment: I have answered you question.  Please upvote and accept it.  Create a new question and then get a new answer.

Comment: how do I pass the whole hex values 0x1020 into a byte, cause the above code is spliting  it into 10 & 20

Comment: 0x1020 **CAN NOT** fit into a byte.  A byte has 8 bits, this value is usually represented as 16 bits.

Comment: is there any other way ?